# How to add css to a feed that is not mine

Tags: html, css, image, rss, feed

I want to separate the image from the text of this RSS with CSS.

http://redbolivia.com/index.php?format=feed&type=rss

Any ideas?  Can I do this with CSS?

---

How do I add CSS to a feed that is not **mine**

---

But I put CSS to the title and the info, but now I want to separate the image from the text because it's too close.
I did this:

```
.rss_item_header
    {
        font-size:14px;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
/* image try */
    .rss_item.img
{
margin:7px;
}


    .rss_item_info
    {
        color:#666;
        font-size:11px;
text-align:justify ;
```

---

Because I dont want to show this feed where the images are next to the info http://redbolivia.com/index.php?format=feed&type=rss
I want to put a margin to this feed, the image is too near.

Answer (score 1):

No. CSS is used for styling elements, not extracting them.

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
    margin: 5px;
    }
```

..Will add a margin of 5px to all sides of all the images on the page. (You stated this isn't your feed.. Why do you need to change this?)